# Raphael, copy image internally

Tags: image, hyperlink, raphael, splice

In Raphael you can load up images in the following manner:

```
var image_one=paper.image("some_url", x,y,width,height);
```

But the thing is that I am splicing the image, and I need several of those cuts, preferably without reloading the original image. That is because loading up only a single large image via http is faster than many small. Apparently there is some overhead in each upload that can become quite substantial.

But anyways, how can I make a copy of a Raphael image, after it has been loaded into ram?
I have already tried:

```
var image_two=image_one;
```

But it seems like that is only creating another link to the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of internal copying is done via [Raphael's .clone()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.animate), which is as simple as this:

```
var newElem = oldElem.clone();
```

`Element.clone()` works on elements including paths, images, rects, circles... [but not sets](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/raphaeljs/sNe2IUXd0CM).

---

Here's a simple demo - play around with splicing as desired.

### http://jsbin.com/ufayuw/1/edit

If you want the clone to be hidden until it is needed, hide it with [`.hide()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.hide)